# VBA chart position changes when rows inserted

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote the following code to add a chart and position it on a worksheet with data on it:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim chrteit As Chart
lastrows = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TraceTable")
Set chrteit = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
With chrteit
.ChartType = xlXYScatter
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = sh.Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(lastrows, 6))
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = sh.Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(lastrows, 7))

    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "EIT"
    .Parent.Height = Range("N2:N14").Height
    .Parent.Width = Range("N2:T2").Width
    .Parent.top = Range("N2").top
    .Parent.Left = Range("N2").Left

End With
```

The problem is, later in my module I have a macro that will an entire row between two data points if the two data points are different, and it is as follows:

```
Private Sub Dividers()

Dim DividerRange As Range, lastrow As Long, k As Integer, counter As Integer

lastrow = Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row

Set DividerRange = Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(lastrow, 3))
counter = 0

For k = 2 To DividerRange.Count
    If DividerRange(k + counter).Value <> DividerRange(k + counter - 1).Value Then
    DividerRange(k + counter).EntireRow.Insert
    counter = counter + 1
    Else
End If
Next k

End Sub
```

By adding the entire row, it changes the height of my graph and it's position. I want it to be a fixed position, how can I do this? I would PREFER not to change the second code, but rather the first but let me know any solutions you guys have, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to the first procedure:

`chrteit.Placement = xlFreeFloating`

This is the same as right-click, format chart area, properties: Don't move or size with cells.
|
Or you could place that method inside the `With` block, thusly:

```
With chrteit
.ChartType = xlXYScatter
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = sh.Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(lastrows, 6))
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = sh.Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(lastrows, 7))

    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "EIT"
    .Parent.Height = Range("N2:N14").Height
    .Parent.Width = Range("N2:T2").Width
    .Parent.top = Range("N2").top
    .Parent.Left = Range("N2").Left

    .Placement = xlFreeFloating
End With
```

Comment: This works great, thank you so much David! I now encounter a new problem though. After my entire macro runs, I run a simple "adjust cells" macro that fits the cells to the text inside it. So basically all the cells shrink a little and the graphs are now far to the right of them. Is there a way to make it free float in just the height direction but not the width direction?

Comment: There's not really a built-in way to do that. The `.Placement` property doesn't have that sort of option.  The neat thing about the `Placement` property is that it works even outside of your macro. You could modify your functions to store the appropriate top/left/width values, and then reset to the stored values after adjusting the cells. And while it's probably possible to replicate the "dynamic" nature of move-but-don't-size as it applies to only a single dimension, it would be a lot of effort to do that, I think.