# prevent programatically generated chart from resing with cells with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The code below creates a chart programmatically but later when new data is imported the chart is deleted.  Is it possible to program the Chart not to resize when data on sheet is filtered? I know this can be set manually but I would like to do this with VBA.  Please let me know if this can’t be done?

```
Set objChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
(Left:=30, Width:=775, Top:=15, Height:=345)
objChart.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
```

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you try the `.Placement` property of the object. Have a look at the accepted answer to this question: [VBA chart position changes when rows inserted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810796/vba-chart-position-changes-when-rows-inserted)

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me.